# CodeIgniter Only Index Page is working

Tags: codeigniter

I recently started using codeIgniter and I am stuck in a problem.

I've two files in my `view` folder

1. index.php
2. profile.php

When I go to the url `http://localhost/php/ci/index.php/` it shows my index.php page and everything is fine.

But when I go to `http://localhost/php/ci/profile.php/` it says

`The requested url was not found on server`.

Why is this happening what's the problem ??

My Controller Files Names Are:

1. home_control.php
2. profile_control.php

home_control will interact with index.php and profile_control will interact with profile.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a fundamental flaw in your MVC understanding. The `index.php` file sitting in your **document root** (that is, your www directory) is actually responsible for getting CodeIgniter started on *every* request. That is the `index.php` that you are seeing in the URL bar.

You are confusing said `index.php` with the `index.php` that *you* fabricated inside of the `views` folder. Never will you be able to create a file inside of your `views` folder and be able to immediately access it using the URL bar. You must go through a controller.

If you access `http://localhost/php/ci/index.php/profile_control` and `controllers/profile_control.php` contains::

```
<?php
class Profile_control extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index(){
        $this->load->view('profile')
    }
}
```

You will be able to see the contents inside of `views/profile.php`

To reduce confusion, [it is essential that you read this before going forward](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/).

Comment: But when I make changes to my `index.php` file present in my view folder and access it via the url i've mentioned the changes can be seen.That means the index.php is working. Yeah I am loading the contents of index.php file from the `home_control.php`(present in the controller folder) using `$this->load->view('index');` as you've mentioned above for the profile.

Comment: when you call that url (from your question) the index.php is the main file. It is not the file that is present in your views, which has the same name yes, but it's not the same file. index.php and applications/views/index.php are 2 different files and you can never call a view file directly from a url. It always goes through a controller which then specifies the view to load.

Answer (score 0):

That is the wrong way to do it, read the manual about how to setup your `.htaccess` file and how routing works. You don't need to have multiple `index.php`-like files, the should only be one.

[Here is the link](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) from where you should start reading.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other said. Everything goes through index.php. But you can actually hide it so that you don't have to type it in the url, which is not pretty btw.

Go to your applications/config/config.php and find something like the following:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";
```

remove the index.php. And in the .htaccess (which is next to your index.php) you need to add this If I'm not mistaken:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If everything works you can call your profile controller like `http://localhost/php/ci/profile_control`. By default it calls the index action so make sure you have an `public function index` in that controller. The url structure is always `http://url.com/*controller*/*action*/*extra params here*`

If you wish to call another action (function) inside your controller, for example `public function profile()`, you can call this url `http://localhost/php/ci/profile_control/profile`.

> It is in that second action that you specify your other view file with **$this->load->view('profile')**. That will call the **view/profile.php** file

You can also pass values to that action like this -> `http://localhost/php/ci/profile_control/profile/id/7`.

in your profile action you need to grab those values as follow

```
public function profile($action, $value)
{
    //$action = the word id and $value = the number 7
}
```

Comment: Thnx for the response. So as I get it. You guys mean that the index.php that i created in the view folder is wrong and the actual index file is already provided in the `application folder`.Now when we will enter controllers from the url as you mentioned.The index function for that controller will execute and present us the page.

Comment: No. What we mean is that the main index.php located next to the applications and system folder is completely different from the index.php you have in the view folder. It's purpose is different. The second part of your comment is mostly correct. It will call the index.php in the view if you specified this in the controller. Have a look at this video tutorial serie, It's a must see if you start with CI. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-1/ , It's from 2009 but it will still give you a good basic understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can create another .htaccess file inside the project folder but outside application folder with the following code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I also had the same issue where only my index page was working and It worked for me!